# SQLSTATE[HY000] when copy-paste with cakephp 4

Tags: mysql, cakephp-4.x

I'm working in cakephp 4 and when I copy-paste a text in a textarea field and I submit my form I have the following error :

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x80pou...' for column 'description' at row 1`

I don't know what is going on... Could anyone help me please ?

Comment: Looks like you may have UNICODE characters in there. Does your column definition support that?

Comment: Thanks @GregSchmidt that was the problem. I 've put all my tables in utf8.